# Gambling problem

Tags: calculation-puzzle

I have a Gambling problem.

One night I go out and get to a casino and do the usual, get my regular at the bar for only $10 tonight at the bar and head over to the tables, I hit a bit of a bad luck streak and lose exactly half my money in my wallet.

I take a break at the bar and have another regular and take another one with me back to the table, But as lady luck would have it I lose half of the money I had left over again.

This has not been my night, I spend my last money on a regular before heading home.

How much money did I walk into the casino with at the start of the night?

Comment: How is this a *puzzle* as opposed to a basic math story problem?

Comment: Can't most logic problems be reduced to set theory making them math problems?

Comment: Puzzles are not exclusively logic problems. (And if all logic problems could be trivially reduced that way, they wouldn't be interesting as puzzles or problems either.) Having said that, this doesn't even require an "a-ha" moment of realization that such an approach works; this is, literally, a rote application of arithmetic.  So I ask again, how is this a *puzzle* as opposed to a basic math story problem?

Comment: Because wouldn't people who don't know that you can apply the logic of the solution have an a-ha moment?

Comment: Listen, I am a newcomer here, I read your help center, I looked for a dupe first. I fixed my broken English and searched for the correct tag, and then get down-voted. I've learned my lesson, and won't post again since you are technically correct and I clearly can't tell the difference and wouldn't want to make the same mistake twice.

Comment: @Rubio now now, it's his first question so no need to be so harsh. The definition of a puzzle is as vague as can be. It is not the kind of puzzle that we usually accept or appreciate on this website, but he will realize that in time.

Comment: @LiefdeWen Firstly, welcome to Puzzling, and I'm sorry that your first question here got closed. If you haven't seen [this meta post](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/2783/5373) yet, you might want to have a read through it: that's the best explanation we have for the difference between a maths problem (off-topic) and a maths puzzle (on-topic). It's a subtle distinction, and lots of people take a while to appreciate it. Please don't let this discourage you - I hope you stick around here and post more nice puzzles :-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor Thank you, I've read through it and will make sure to reread it if I ever post something again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets reverse this,

> 0->10(buy the last drink)
> 10->20(Lost half the money)
> 20->40(10x2 drinks)
> 40->80(lost half the money)
> 80->90(1 drink)
> So you had 90$. Not such a big loss if you had fun!

Comment: Nice. You got it.